# Round Robin League Seeding Logic MVC and EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need help with seeding data in a league with 12 teams, each team has a TeamId key value of 1 to 12 respectively

I have pre-populated and seeded the ScheduledFixtures table with 22 rows. In my attempt below I do a take 11 while i try to set up the first half of season, i.e. everyone plays everyone once. Each week for each team has to be home game, then away game

My code is at a point where it works in that it seeds the right number of rows but the wrong teamId's are set in fixture game. This is the bit I cannot figure out. So ScheduleFixture 1 loops once and I need each team to play each other, then next loop same again but who was at home is now away etc etc

```
        var sheduledFixtures = db.ScheduledFixtures.Take(22);
        var teams = db.Teams;
        foreach (var x in sheduledFixtures)
        {
            var i = 1;

            for (int t = 1; t < 8; t++)
            {

                if (t != i)
                {
                    var fixtureGame = new FixtureGame();

                        fixtureGame.AwayTeamId = i;
                        fixtureGame.HomeTeamId = t;

                    db.FixtureGames.Add(fixtureGame);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    // Add Fixture Record
                    var fixture = new Fixture();
                    fixture.FixtureGameId = fixtureGame.FixtureGameId;
                    fixture.SeasonId = 1;
                    fixture.ScheduledFixtureId = x.ScheduledFixtureId;
                    db.Fixtures.Add(fixture);

                    i++;
                }          
            }      

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I only get teamIds from 1 - 7 at the moment. I need to get 1-12 each loop of the outer loop, i.e. each Schedule Fixture

Comment: `for (int t = 1; t < 8; t++)` what about changing 8 to 13?

Comment: That gets me all the keys but does not implement the round robin